# Send JWT token to server upon initial browser request (using local storage)

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, local-storage, token

Okay, let's say I have a login page where when the user logs in he or she gets a JWT token from the server which is then saved in local storage (I know cookies is better but I want to do it with local storage). After that, imagine I quit my browser (token is still in local storage and in this example has no expiration date). Now what I want is the following: After quitting the browser (but I got successfully logged in and have token in local storage) how do I make it so that upon initial request to the same server I don't get the login page up again but instead have the user already signed in? Taje into an account that I am able to authenticate the user after the first request and I am aware how but How do I send the token in the initial request?

Comment: Since JWTs are stateless, you should be sending the token to the server with every request anyway. Why would the first one be any different?

Comment: How do I send it though? I mean I have quit the browser and my token sits in local storage how would I make it so that upon initial request (me typing the URL in a brand new tab) I get the token from the local storage be sent to the server? @MTCoster

Comment: Traditionally, session tokens (of any kind, not just JWT) are stored as cookies. Cookies are sent in the headers of every HTTP request by the browser. Storing your token as a cookie also allows you to set the `HttpOnly` flag as [an effective defence against XSS](https://blog.codinghorror.com/protecting-your-cookies-httponly/). As you're storing your token in LocalStorage, presumably you have some JS mechanism for sending it to the server. Why not just make your first request if the token is present, and present the login page if you receive an `Unauthorized` response?

Comment: "*I know cookies is better but I want to do it with local storage*" Why? What benefit are you getting by doing this?

Comment: Well now that I think about it not sure if there is a benefit of using local storage so I will try doing it with cookies and see how things work out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may not be a direct solution to your requirement.
But, One hack can be added by adding Script in Head tag.
And withing this script you check if localStorage.getItem('key') is present or not.

If value is present send the request to Home Page directly along with Token or else Login Page.

But, this script download is extra server round-trip.

Comment: That is true and did think of this, tried it but don't like how things work together with the rest of my application.